# Static pulsing sound produced from internal microphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype, microphone

Any sound recorded or used from my laptop's built in microphones is distorted. My voice is barely audible. However, there is a very prominent static pulsing sound. The audio waveform of a recording from the microphone resembles a sine wave, with about 2 or 3 waves per second. Sometimes the microphone simply stops taking any input at all, but a reboot will return it to a state in which it records the static sound.

I can hear this myself when recording with arecord or any other recording application, and I've been told that I sound horribly distorted over various different voice chat applications like Skype.

Solutions that I have attempted are adjusting the microphone input volume slider in GNOME settings, and changing the default sample rate in pulseaudio to match the laptop's hardware as specified [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Static_noise_in_microphone_recording).

I have experienced this in multiple different Linux distributions, but the microphones work perfectly fine in Windows. I have attempted these fixes on the most recent releases of Ubuntu and Fedora, but the problem was not solved in either case.

The laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 920, and the microphone hardware according to arecord is:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any guidance on how to solve the issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem on Kubuntu 18.04. My microphone device is named "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo", as inferred executing: `pacmd list-sources | grep 'name:.*input'`.
You can find the main reference to fix the problem [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_distorted_due_to_automatic_adjustment), some paragraphs below that one you linked.
Editing all the /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input*.conf files fixed the issue in my case.
I can share you a simple bash script which I used to automate the process:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -nP "(Element Capture)|(Element \w+ Mic)|(Element Mic)" /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input*.conf | while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do

    IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< "${LINE}"
    path="${array[0]}";
    num="${array[1]}";
    element="${array[2]}";


    for i in $(seq 5 $END); do
         
        param="$(sed -n "$((num + i))p" < "$path")"
        if [[ $param == "volume ="* ]]; then
            echo "processing line $path:$((num + i))";
            echo "replacing <$param> with <volume = zero>";
            sed -i "$((num + i))s/.*/volume = zero/" "$path";
        fi
    done

done
```

Restart PulseAudio to apply the changes:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Finally check by recording your voice and playing it back:

```
arecord -f cd -d 10 test-mic.wav
aplay test-mic.wav
```

Comment: I get 3: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: Hi @Tachytaenius, probably the problem was caused by the missing shebang, I edited my post: add it and retry launching the script